# What does CreateDirectory[] return?

Tags: files-and-directories

Based on:

> `CreateDirectory` returns the full name of the directory it creates, and
>   `$Failed` if it cannot create the directory

the following code should return `True` on each comparison, but it doesn't.

For this reason I wonder if CreateDirectory[], on a succesfull try, gives the same string it got as argument. Please, can you explain ?

By the way, in this site is allowed talking about looking for some sort of employment as Mathematica programmer?

```
folder = "c:\\something";
If[
  DirectoryQ[folder],
  Quiet[
   DeleteDirectory[folder]
   ], Null, Null
  ];
data = CreateDirectory[folder];
FullForm /@ {folder, data}
folder == data
folder === data
FullForm[folder] == FullForm[data]
FullForm[folder] === FullForm[data]
```

Comment: Are you looking for a job?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if my skill in Mathematica (and English ...) suffices to decently putting me in for a job and yes, at present I'm looking for a part time job.

Comment: I think you can get what `CreateDirectory` will return with `ExpandFileName` without actually creating the directory. For your example I think `ExpandFileName[folder]===data` should return True when the `CreateDirectory` was successful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateDirectory returns the name of the parent directory as Capital litter

```
data = CreateDirectory[folder]
(*"C:\\something"*)
```

When you try to use Equal or similar, it done' know anything about the folder but it compares values in hand.

Defiantly `"c:\\something"` dose not equal `"C:\\something"` because the `"c"` does not equal `"C"`.

To get what you want use :

```
folder = "C:\\something";

folder == data
folder === data
FullForm[folder] == FullForm[data]
FullForm[folder] === FullForm[data]

(*True*)
(*True*)
(*True*)
(*True*)
```

For your second question, as far as I know this not a place to post job offers but you can for sure look at the page of the users and if they put their contact you can contact them personally

Comment: I think this is not completely correct: As I pointed out (and verified) in my answer, `CreateDirectory` does return not only the parent directory, but the full path.

Comment: Capital letters ! I'm ashamed for having asked a such silly question. I should have realized it: I apologise.

Answer (score 6):

`CreateDirectory` does not return what was input, but the **full path** to the directory created: Try:

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Temp"];
CreateDirectory["abcdefg12345"]
(* C:\\Temp\\abcdefg12345 *)
```

In your case, the difference is between the lowercase "c" and the returned uppercase "C", so the comparison fails for that reason.

Comment: there might also other changes be done, see e.g. what `CreateDirectory["c:/ttt"]` returns on windows, I'd probably formulate that as "does not return what was input, but a normalized full path to the directory created"...